# Finding another encoder for a given code

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I am a newcomer in Coding Theory and I am trying to solve the following question:
\begin{equation*}
\text{Let}\ \mathscr{C} \subset \mathbb{F}_3^4 \text{ be a code}, \text{with racio } 2/4, \text{and with the following encoder},
     G_1=\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
         2 & 0 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}.
 \text{Find another encoder}  \ G_2 \text{ of } \mathscr{C} \text{ such that } G_2=[I_2 \hspace{2mm} A] \text{ for some matrix  }A∈ \mathbb{F^{2\times 2}}.
\end{equation*}

$\textbf{This is my attempt to solve the question:}$
I know that that if $G_1 \in \mathbb{F}^{k \times n}$ is a encoder of $\mathscr{C}$, and $U \in \mathbb{F}^{k \times k}$ is an invertible matrix, and $G_2=U G_1$ then $G_2$ is also an encoder of $\mathscr{C}$. So I though I could just define a random matrix $U$, like, for example,
\begin{equation*}
U=\begin{bmatrix}
          0 & 2 \\
         1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
such that $U$ is invertible (which is true because $\det(U)= -2 \neq 0$). And then do the multiplication $UG_1$ to find $A$:

\begin{equation*} G_2=UG_1 \Leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
         0 & 1 & a_{21} & a_{22}
     \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
          0 & 2 \\
         1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
         2 & 0 & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix} \Leftrightarrow \
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
         0 & 1 & a_{21} & a_{22}
     \end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
         0 & 1 & 2 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $A=\begin{bmatrix}
          2 & 2 \\
          2 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}$, and we have another encoder for our code $\mathscr{C}$,  $G_2=\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
         0 & 1 & 2 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}$.

$\textbf{Is my resolution correct?}$
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A problem with your method is the choice of a *random* matrix $U$. Instead, if $G=(G_1 \mid G_2)$, where $G_1$ is a square block, you should select $U=G_1^{-1}$. If $G_1$ is invertible, then no generator matrix with the required structure exists. But, the simplest way to achieve this is to put $G$ into the reduced row echelon form using the methods you learned in linear algebra. The run of the algorithm will either find the alternative generator matrix, or allow you to conclude that it cannot be done.

Comment: (cont'd) In the latter case the first $k$ symbols of the codewords have linear dependencies. In other words, they are not all information carrying symbols (one or more check symbols slipped in).